# Adding the Octopus build number to a project level variable

Tags: powershell, deployment, octopus-deploy, octopus

I have a project variable of {#ServiceVersion} in one of my config files and i need ot be able to set this to the octopus release number that's stored in the octopus variables.

I've tried the basic PowerShell script that looks something like this:

```
$ServiceVersion = "$($OctopusParameters['Octopus.Release.Number'])";
```

But that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Tell us what happened when running your code. _"doesnt seem to work"_ does not provide any information. Error messages? Please post these in your question as well.

Answer (score 1):

To alias an Octopus system variable, you'll need to add it as a variable to your project.

[image: ServiceVersion as a project variable in Octopus]

Then you can use the variable with one of the configuration substitution features.